# Gstreamer, alsa, bluealsa: bluetooth audio not working in 2 ways audio stream

Tags: audio, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, alsa

### Context

So I have 2 Gstreamer pipelines, one to send audio up (PC to Pi) to a Raspberry Pi, and another to send audio down (Pi to PC).

The audio down is getting sound from a USB mic and the audio up is outputting sound to a Bluetooth speaker.

The libraries uses are Alsa with Bluez.

### Problem

Here is where it gets complicated:

- [✓] The audio up alone, is working
- [✓] The audio down alone is working

But:

- **[✗] If the audio down is simultaneous, the audio up is not working**

  Somehow, Bluetooth audio-out is not working when listening at the same time to a capture device.

However:

- [✓] If the audio up is outputting to a non-Bluetooth device (e.g with the jack connector) it is working fine, even simultaneously with audio down.

**In other words**: the output the the Bluetooth device is working, only if I am not listening to a capture device simultaneously, while if the output device is not Bluetooth, it is working no matter what.

*"Not working" means that the audio cannot be heard on the speaker.*

#### Question

How can I get the Bluetooth device to work with GStreamer even when a capture device is listening ?

### Code

##### Audio Down

Send audio down

```py
 import gi
 gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')

 # gst-launch-1.0
 cmd  =  ' alsasrc device=hw:1,0 ! audio/x-raw ! queue '
 cmd +=  '  ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! avenc_ac3 ! queue '
 cmd += f'  ! rtpac3pay ! udpsink host={ip} port={port} '
```

##### Audio Up

Receive audio and output to bluetooth speaker

```py
 # gst-launch-1.0
 cmd =  f'udpsrc port={port} ! decodebin ! audioresample ! audioconvert '
 cmd += f' ! alsasink device=bluealsa:DEV={MAC_ADDRESS} '
```

Receive audio and output to normal speaker (e.g. jack or USB)

```py
 # gst-launch-1.0
 cmd =  f'udpsrc port={port} ! decodebin ! audioresample ! audioconvert '
 cmd +=  ' ! alsasink device=hw:2,0 '
```

#### Notes

I am using the python library for Gstreamer.